# I want to fill out the list before passing it as a parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fill out the list before passing it as a parameter.

places, it stays in null, I have tried to return it with the function but it tells me that it is not compatible Future to list.

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppState({
    places,
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){
    getPois();
  }

  List<Place> places = [];
  PlaceCategory selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo;
  PlaceTrackerViewType viewType;

  void getPois() async {
    final poi = await fetchPois();
    final resType = await fetchPoisTypes();
    poi.pois.forEach((element) {
      places.add(Place(
        id: element.poi.id!,
        latLng: LatLng(double.parse(element.poi.longitud!),double.parse(element.poi.latitud!)),
        name: element.poi.nombreEs!,
        description: element.poi.nombreEs! +" "+element.poi.informacionEs!,
        starRating: 3,
        category: PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
      ));
      //print(LatLng(double.parse(element.poi.latitud), double.parse(element.poi.longitud)));
    });
    resType.forEach((element) {
      places.add(Place(
        id: element.poiType.id!,
        latLng: LatLng(1.1, 1.1),
        name: element.poiType.tipoEs!,
        description: element.poiType.explicacionEs,
        starRating: 0,
        category: PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
      ));
    });
    notifyListeners();
}
```

Comment: If you are going to fetch it internally, then why you place it in constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is a misunderstanding of the `async` statement of the `getPois` method.
`async` will allow Dart to delay the execution of the method. It acts somehow like a corouting, which is a non-parallel multitasking. In Flutter, it is used for example to avoid blocking operations (the Flutter/Dart engine can delay async method calls to prioritize screen drawing.
You could check for the existence of your `List` after calling `await getPois();`.

This explains that you can't return the list. Since your method is marked `async`, it has to return a future. So you could make it return a `Future<List<Place>>`.

Comment: `type of type 'Future<List<Place>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Place>'. (Documentation)  Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'List<Place>'.`  thank you very much for your reply__ now I get this err

Comment: This code works :  
`   
Future<List<int>> getList() async   
{  
  List<int> l = List.generate(5, (int index){return index;});  
  return l;  
}   

   
void f() async   
{   
  List<int> l = await getList();   
  for(int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {   
    print(l[i]);   
  }   
}   
`
You can call the `f()` function, it works fine. This error you get is probably beccause your List is a member list, so it might be pointless to return it in the same object. If you need to get it from another object, just return a reference, or return a copy.

Comment: yes, it is work but I want to pass list to AppState, now I get error "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. (Documentation)"                             class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppState({
    this.places = f(),
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){
    //getPois();
    f();
  }

Comment: thanks, how I can pass this list to constructor, i get an error can a cast futur to my list?

Comment: If you want to pass it to constructor, it must be a list, not a future. So first await the list to be constructed. Than pass it to a constructor synchronously.

Comment: ok,   // how I can call fn getPois(); before pass params to AppState  ``class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {

  AppState({
    //this.places = getPois() as List<Place>,
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){
    getPois();
  }``

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap it like this:

```
class AppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  AppState({
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){
    _initialize();
  }

  final List<Place> _places = <Place>[];
  final PlaceCategory selectedCategory;
  final PlaceTrackerViewType viewType;

void getPois() async {
    final poi = await fetchPois();
    final resType = await fetchPoisTypes();
    poi.pois.forEach((element) {
      _places.add(Place(
        id: element.poi.id!,
        latLng: LatLng(double.parse(element.poi.longitud!),double.parse(element.poi.latitud!)),
        name: element.poi.nombreEs!,
        description: element.poi.nombreEs! +" "+element.poi.informacionEs!,
        starRating: 3,
        category: PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
      ));
      //print(LatLng(double.parse(element.poi.latitud), double.parse(element.poi.longitud)));
    });
    resType.forEach((element) {
      _places.add(Place(
        id: element.poiType.id!,
        latLng: LatLng(1.1, 1.1),
        name: element.poiType.tipoEs!,
        description: element.poiType.explicacionEs,
        starRating: 0,
        category: PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
      ));
    });
    notifyListeners();
  }


    Future<void> _initialize() async{
        await getPois();
    }
}
```

Comment: when I try to pass _places to AppState I get error, _Places The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.     AppState({
    this.places = places,
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){
    _initialize();
  }
  List<Place> places = <Place>[];
  PlaceCategory selectedCategory;
  PlaceTrackerViewType viewType;
  Future<void> _initialize() async{
    getPois();
  }

Comment: what..? dont you intend to fetch it with getPois() after AppState instantiated? then why would you want to give AppState _places? We already removes _places from AppState constructor if you want to pass it then you can re-add it, and rename it from _places -> places so that it visible as public.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ,: ((I don't get what I'm looking for or if it's possible.
I want to store the list in AppState like other params, but it tells me that the optional parameters must be constant, or the future list cannot be converted to List places.          AppState(places,{
    this.selectedCategory = PlaceCategory.wantToGo,
    this.viewType = PlaceTrackerViewType.map,
  }){          void main() {
  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (context) => AppState(getPois()),
    child: PlaceTrackerApp(),
  ));
}